# Building an inverted climbing wall onto a tree?

Tags: structural, play-structures, treehouse

We have a cottonwood tree in our back yard with a treehouse in it, I have one vertical climbing wall on one side, but we're thinking of putting an inverted wall on the other. The tree is one large tree that branches into 8 trunks about 3ft off the ground. One of the trunks is at about a 50-60° angle to the ground and about 13-15" in diameter, the guy I'm planning this with thinks that we could just build right off of the trunk, but I'm concerned about how the trunk will support the weight. It probably could support the wall, but I'm not sure. I'm wondering if it would be better to build the wall *around* the tree or if I'd be ok attaching it to the tree. Or if anyone else has any great suggestions?

Comment: Not sure what "inverted" means in this case. Tilted back toward climber, or something else?

Comment: @keshlam - Sorry, climbing lingo. Yes, climbing inverted means that you are on a wall that is over hung, when a slope is *past* vertical and you hang off the holds as opposed to standing on them while you climb.